# Point estimate of a parameter out of the interval of allowable parameter values

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

I have a question about point estimators. In general, if I have an estimator for a parameter, let's say $p$, and $p \in (0, 1)$,and out of the obtained data I get that the point estimate equals $-0.01$, what should be the conclusion? 
That the estimator cannot be used or that we should get more data and recalculate the estimator or should I say the estimate is 0? But $p\in (0,1)$ and 0 is not in the interval.
I got this from a real situation, the point estimators work perfectly for more data but sometimes for less data, they just don't give me a result in the interval $(0,1)$

A bit similar problem is when i want to estimate the parameter p from bernoulli distribution. The reasonable point estimator is $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{n}$ where $x_i$ are obtained data. And my obtained data is $(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),$ then the estimator gives us 0 but 0 is not in $(0,1)$. So what is the conclusion? 
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

There are various situations in frequentist statistics that may lead to an estimate of a parameter $\theta$ outside the range in which $\theta$ is defined.
Sometimes a better estimator can be found that does not present this difficulty.

I wish you had given an example in which $\hat \theta = -0.01$ and by definition $0 < \theta < 1.$ Then I might have been able to give an explanation for this behavior, and perhaps suggest an interpretation. (An embarrassingly  common interpretation is something like, "Oh well, $\theta > 0$ must be ***really*** small.)

> *Examples, without giving all the details:*
>
> (a) One such instance arises when the prevalence of a disease is estimated from the fraction of subjects with a positive result on a medical screening test. Screening tests
>   are not perfect. Even in a population with no diseased subjects, one expects
>   a certain proportion of (false) positive results. If the observed proportion of positive
>   tests is *lower* than this expected proportion, then the estimate of disease
>   prevalence may be negative. See Example 5.2 in Suess (2010): *Intro. to Probability simulation...* .
>
> (b) Consider a one-way random effects ANOVA with model
>   $Y_{ij} = \mu + A_i + e_{ij},$ where 
>   $A_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma_A)$ and]
>   $e_{ij} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma_e).$ One can
>   sometimes estimate $\sigma_A$ by a formula that involves subtraction of
>   two (positive) sums of squares. But if $\sigma_A$ is small compared with $\sigma_e,$
>   the difference, and thus the estimate of $\sigma_A,$ may be negative--an
>   nonsensical result.

By contrast, in Bayesian statistics, one would begin with a prior distribution
with strictly positive support -- perhaps a Beta or gamma distribution. Then the posterior
distribution, used for estimation, must have strictly positive support, and such 'illegal' estimates cannot occur. [This is hardly the main reason for using a Bayesian framework
for inference, but it *is* a nice side-effect.]

The example in your second paragraph is more of a philosophical issue than
a probabilistic one. If $0$ data values are possible, then it seems one might start
with $0 \le \theta \le 1$ (and regard $0^0 \approx \epsilon^0$ as a limit with value $1$).